# Authorization Request failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Client Registration with Id: linkedin

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        google:
          clientId: #############################
          clientSecret: #############################
          redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          scope:
            - email
            - profile
        facebook:
          clientId: ##################
          clientSecret: ###############################
          redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          scope:
            - email
            - public_profile
        github:
          clientId: #######################
          clientSecret: ###########################
          redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          scope:
            - user:email
            - read:user
        linkedin:
          client:
            clientId: ##############
            clientSecret: ##################
            redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            scope: r_liteprofile r_emailaddress
            clientAuthenticatioMethod: POST
      provider:
        facebook:
          authorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
          tokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token
          userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
```

This is my application.yml page. I Have used code from this [Link](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/) for integrating linkedIn like facebook and google.

but it is showing error

> Authorization Request failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Client Registration with Id: linkedin

Kindly help me out in this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Gaurav-Manwani, do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Properties you provided seem to be incorrect in following line:

```
    linkedin:
          client: <--- this is unwanted
            clientId: ##############
            clientSecret: ##################
            redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            scope: r_liteprofile r_emailaddress
            clientAuthenticatioMethod: POST
```

You should remove line with "client" and keep like this:

```
   linkedin:
      clientId: ##############
      clientSecret: ##################
      redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
      scope: r_liteprofile r_emailaddress
      clientAuthenticatioMethod: POST
```

Like the above ones. I suppose you should also include provider for linkedin to make OAuth working.